# Product ID not being added in my database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.x

Hi I have created a database wnad when I try to insert data into it everything is added accept for the product ID. Here is the code I have.

Database creation,

```
import sqlite3

def create_table(db_name,table_name,sql):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",(table_name,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        keep_table = True
    if len(result) == 1:
            response = input("The table {0} already exists, do you want to recreate it (y/n)?:  ".format(table_name))
        if response == "y":
            keep_table = False
            print("The table {0} will be recreated - all existing data will be lost.".format(table_name))
            cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format(table_name))
            db.commit()
        else:
            print("The existing table was kept")
    else:
        keep_table = False
    if not keep_table:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_name = "coffee_shop.db"
    sql = """create table Product
             (ProductID intiger,
             Name text,
             Price real,
             primary key(ProductID))"""
create_table(db_name, "Product", sql)
```

and then I was using this to insert data

```
import sqlite3

def insert_data(values):
    with sqlite3.connect("coffee_shop.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "insert into Product (Name, Price) values (?,?)"
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()
name = input("what is the product called?:  ")
value = float(input("How much does it cost?:  "))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    product = ("{0}".format(name),"{0}".format(value))
    insert_data(product)
```

And this is what my database ends up like, without a product id:
[image: Database screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave your `ProductID` the type `intiger`; that is not a type SQLite recognizes. Correct that to be `integer` and the column will auto-increment.

See [SQLite Autoincrement](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for more details.

Comment: Yup, just one little letter difference. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters They are not, [only INTEGER works for `rowid`s](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

Comment: @CL.: Bugger, you are correct. I had not read on far enough to the section that specifically states that affinity doesn't apply. :-/ Thanks for hitting me over the head properly.